# numerical integration with intermediate variables

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerics

I'm trying to perform the following integral, where the bounds of the inner integrals become the integration variable in the next integral.

disregarding the stuff in the exponential in the sample equation below, my code is as follows using NIntegrate[].

The problem is that I'm still having problems with the bounds of integration. Based on the outermost bounds of this integral (2 to 5), I should get a numerical value.

```
tUnlooped[R_?NumericQ, R1_?NumericQ, R2_] = NIntegrate[
Exp[
 -(
    -Log[
     R^2*((2*Pi*L*b^(2/3))^(-3/2))*
      Exp[-3*(Sqrt[(R - b)^2 + b^2 - 2*b*(R - b)])^2/(2*L*b^2)]]
   +
   -2*eps/(1 + Exp[Sqrt[(R - b)^2 + b^2 - 2*b*(R - b)]/sig]))
+ (-Log[
    R1^2*((2*Pi*L*b^(2/3))^(-3/2))*
     Exp[-3*(Sqrt[(R1 - b)^2 + b^2 - 2*b*(R1 - b)])^2/(2*L*b^2)]] +
  -2*eps/(1 + Exp[Sqrt[(R1 - b)^2 + b^2 - 2*b*(R1 - b)]/sig])
 )
-
(-Log[
    R2^2*((2*Pi*L*b^(2/3))^(-3/2))*
     Exp[-3*(Sqrt[(R2 - b)^2 + b^2 - 2*b*(R2 - b)])^2/(2*L*b^2)]] +
  -2*eps/(1 + Exp[Sqrt[(R2 - b)^2 + b^2 - 2*b*(R2 - b)]/sig])
 )
],{R2, 2, R1}, {R1, R, 5}, {R, 2, 5}]
```

[image]

would really appreciate guidance with this; the stack pages I referenced used plots, but I should actually be getting a numerical value here.

Comment: Have you defined `eps`, `L`, `b`, etc.?  If so, then you've got the syntax backwards for the limits: it should be `{R, 2, 5},  {R1, R, 5}, {R2, 2, R1}`.

Comment: yes! b = 1; 
L = 35;
kT = 4.16*10^(-21);
kbT = 298;
eps = 23.5;
sig = 1.3;

Comment: i fixed the bounds of integration the only problem is that I'm not getting a numerical value from this and I'm unclear how to run it so that I do... if I vary R I should get different values. when I do this, nothing happens.

Comment: I'm not sure why you've defined this as a function of `R`, `R1`, and `R2`, since you are integrating over all of those variables. If you just do the `NIntegrate` on its own, with those numbers plugged in and the order of the limits correct, it spits out a number.

Comment: i was trying to emulate what i had seen with stack previously

Answer (score 1):

Be aware, that the integration begins with the outermost integration variable:

Defining

```
\[Beta]Fmin[R_?NumericQ] := (-Log[R^2*((2*Pi*L*b^(2/3))^(-3/2))*Exp[-3*(Sqrt[(R - b)^2 + b^2 - 2*b*(R - b)])^2/(2*L*b^2)]] + -2*eps/(1 + Exp[Sqrt[(R - b)^2 + b^2 - 2*b*(R - b)]/sig]))
```

the integral evaluates to

```
NIntegrate[Exp[-\[Beta]Fmin[R] + \[Beta]Fmin[R1] - \[Beta]Fmin[R2]],
{R, 2,5}, {R1, R, 5}, {R2, 2, R1}]  
(*4.88353*10^12*)
```